# AuthorizeAttribute to handle valid authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a implemented a custom AuthorizeAtrribute class

```
public class AdminAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Action method

```
[AdminAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ViewResult AdminOnly()
{
    return View();
}

[AdminAuthorize(Roles = "Admin, Mod")]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

When I have a user that IsAuthenticated but not in the Admin role I would like to redirect them to the Index page and not the logon page.

I've read the many other SO posts on this **but my HandleUnauthorizedRequest() method is not firing.**

Comment: Right now, your custom attribute doesn't do anything, as all you're doing in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` is calling the base method.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Correct but it's not hitting the breakpoints at all

Comment: ChrisPratt is right you doing nothing in your custom attribute you need to ovverride AuthorizeCore do something like getting all your role than HandleUnauthorizedRequest will get call

Comment: @DarkVision So HandleUnauthorizedRequest() will never get called unless I also overwrite AuthorizeCore() ?

Comment: AuthorizeCore return a bool to check is your role will have the right access if it return false than HandleUnauthorizedRequest will call

Comment: @DarkVision My user is logged in with only the "Mod" role, when I attempt to access the AdminOnly() action I'm redirected to the login page. So the authorization appears to be working correctly but HandleUnauthorizedRequest() is still not firing. I guess I'm just confused to why it doesn't fire when everything else seems to be working as it should.

Comment: HandleUnauthorizedRequest will not know the role you explicit tell him in the attribute that why you need define code in AuthorizeCore to check if the user have the right to access

Comment: @DarkVision Would you mind providing a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this the code i always use when i work with active directory

```
public string Groups { get; set; }

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups)) { return true; }

        var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();

        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"yourDomain");

        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,IdentityType.SamAccountName,httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        foreach(var group in groups){ // this will check user if the right role in active directory
            if(userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var result = new ViewResult();
        result.ViewName = "NotAuthorized";
        result.MasterName = "_Layout";
        filterContext.Result = result;
    }
    else
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

forgot to tell the Groups variable represent the field inside my Attribute

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = ConstantsADGroups.AdminGp)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding a method that is later in the process than you think.  You'll need to override one of these methods to implement your auth logic:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        //do custom work here
    }
```

OR

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (!base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
            return false;

        //do custom work here
    }
```